# How can I get the class type from inside a generic?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
    public void Delete<T, V>(T item, V repo)
        where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
        where V : IAzureTable<T>
    {
        try
        {
            repo.Delete(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ex.Errors.Add("", "Error when deleting");
            throw _ex;
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to have the error message return "Error when deleting Account" or "Error when deleting Content".  Account and Content are the class names (T). How can I get the actual name of the class and append to the error string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typeof(T).FullName
```

or

```
typeof(T).Name
```

Comment: That's the way I'd do it too, but @Melissa, don't forget you'll get the class name, which might be unfriendly. You might want to have a way to change these names into friendlier ones.